# UnrealEngine - Replace actor keeps old name in World Outliner

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

When I’m designing a level I often “ALT+Drag” to duplicate an asset and then switch a mesh.

While doing this, the asset keeps it’s original name in the World Outliner so it would often happen that mesh name is Wall, but the actual mesh in the viewport is a Rock.

Here is the screenshot showing World outliner.
[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoPqg.png)

So for example, 5 “Skeleton_Slave_Shackels” are shown in the World Outliner, but only 1 of them is actually “Skeleton_Slave_Shackels”, while others are Rock meshes which kept the “Skeleton_Slave_Shackels” name.

Is there any workaround for this? Can I do something to force or update the names in the world outliner to match the names of the mesh?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do it. The problem is that you are copying the `Static Mesh` with all its properties. Even though it's a fast way to make your scene, the alt-drag or duplicate function does exactly what he says. I suggest you to modify the name of the first rock you put in the scene and then alt-drag all the rocks from the initial one to keep the name of the mesh + progressive number automatically generated.